# How to get stack trace from the caller in Java

Tags: java

In Java, I want to get the stack trace of how the calls were made to which methods. How can I achieve that?

For example, my call stack is:

```
class Example {
   public void init() {
      func1();
      // TODO : now here I want to print the stack trace that it went from:
      // func1
      // func2
      // func3
   }
   public void func1() {
      func2();
   }
   public void func2() {
      func3();
   }
   public void func3() {
      // some code here
   }
    

}
```

Comment: Once you're in the caller, the ship has sailed. You can only do this inside the funcX() methods.

Comment: You can maintain a stack yourself by having a custom variable of type Stack (of string) and PUSH (say function name) to stack right before you call it. and then POP all of them where you want.

Comment: Do you control the other methods (func1, func2, etc)? Are you able to add code to those other methods?

Comment: No I dont necessarily control the other methods. I cant add code to them

Comment: Let's rule out the possibility that this may be a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why do you need the list of methods that were called?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want

```
class Example {
  public void init() {
     func1();
     // TODO : now here I want to print the stack trace that it went from:
     try { throw new Throwable("Debugging") } catch (Throwable t) { t.printStackTrace(); }
     // or
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()));
     // func1
     // func2
     // func3
  }
  public void func1() {
     func2();
  }
  public void func2() {
     func3();
  }
  public void func3() {
     // some code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thats not what I want. I want to know which all methods did the `init()` method call

Comment: Actually your code will just print `init` and the method that called it. It will not print `func1` nor `func2` nor `func3`. It always intrigues me why people up-vote an answer that does not answer the question. By the way, the code in your answer does not compile. It is missing a semicolon in the `try` block. Did you test your code before posting? Or did you make a mistake when you copied your code to the answer?

Comment: The first example does not need a try block, it is same as `new Throwable("Debugging").printStackTrace();`

Comment: @DuncG or just use [`Thread#dumpStack()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#dumpStack())

Answer (score 0):

Use a IDE and make use of breakpoints.
Personally, I use IntelliJ.
You can add breakpoints to your code. Breakpoints will make your program halt when they get hit. At that time you can see call stack in Debugger window under IntelliJ.
IntelliJ provides great support for debugging, and also provides easy tutorials to get started with IntelliJ Debugger Tool.
If you want to print Stack Trace, then make use of **Thread.currentThread.getStackTrace()** function.

Comment: This will work in small projects or when you can look at the debugger. Printing a stacktrace can go into a logfile for later evaluation also, so your contribution does not answer the question.